# How to apply theme on MaterialButton or RaisedButton?

Tags: flutter

Can someone help to point how do we define base theme for button and use it on every button? Everywhere I look only found `textTheme` but not `buttonTheme` example?

Even on `buttonTheme` how do we define text colors? 
Because on the button itself we can do it directly like `color: Colors.blue`

Comment: There is a [`ButtonTheme`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ButtonTheme-class.html) class that can use with [`ButtonThemeData`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ButtonThemeData-class.html)

Comment: Yes but how? I'm sorry if I ask basic question, very new to Flutter

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One way to do it is to Define `buttonTheme` in `theme` in `MaterialApp`:

E.g:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
    theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.redAccent,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
           buttonColor: Colors.blueAccent,
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
           textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
           ....
    )),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Button Theme"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green),
      body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton( //Button Color is as define in theme
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text("Send"), //Text Color as define in theme
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

with this all the Buttons defined under this `MaterialApp`will Carry this Theme Style.

Text Color will be the `accentColor` define in the `ThemeData` as i have defined `textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent` so it will Pick `accentColor`

Button picking Theme Style As Defined in `theme`

Comment: Thanks but how to apply this buttonTheme to a button? I have put this buttonTheme on main.dart and I want to apply this theme to all buttons across dart files

Comment: When you define Raised Button in home: Home() Class it will pick up this Theme Style. You don't need to mention anything anywhere.

Comment: Added the code for showing Button picking that Theme Style.

Comment: Wow thanks I didn't know that. I was struggling with all those data: themeData copyWith get context and so on just trying to apply it....

Comment: But it didn't work for MaterialButton? And when should I use RaisedButton or RaisedButton or even FlatButton?

Comment: Rather than using this MaterialButton class directly, consider using FlatButton, OutlineButton, or RaisedButton, which configure this class with appropriate defaults that match the material design specification. To create a button directly, without inheriting theme defaults, use RawMaterialButton.

Comment: check - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialButton-class.html for Info & use case

Comment: FlatButton, a material design button without a shadow. RaisedButton, a filled button whose material elevates when pressed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out I'll do more reading on this @anmol.majhail

Comment: Still I don't find when consider to use MaterialButton?

Answer (score 41):

**[August 2020 - Flutter 1.20]**

Since 1.20 you can create different button theme configurations based on button types.

Sample code for color settings:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
      theme: ThemeData.from(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(),
      ).copyWith(
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.orange,
          ),
        ),
        elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            onPrimary: Colors.yellow,
            primary: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
        outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.purple,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('TextButton'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('ElevatedButton'),
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('OutlinedButton'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Important** release notes from flutter (you can find more information about the options in the migration guide):

> FlatButton, RaisedButton, and OutlineButton have been replaced by TextButton, ElevatedButton, and OutlinedButton respectively. ButtonTheme has been replaced by TextButtonTheme, ElevatedButtonTheme, and OutlinedButtonTheme. The original classes will be deprecated soon, please migrate code that uses them. There's a detailed migration guide for the new button and button theme classes in [flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide](https://flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide).

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you also need to provide textColor to your button. 
How about creating your Custom Button?

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color textColor;
  final Color buttonColor;
  final Function() onPressed;
  MyButton({
    @required this.text,
    this.buttonColor = const Color(0xFF000000) /** Default buttonColor */,
    @required this.onPressed,
    this.textColor = const Color(0xFFDDDDDD) /** Default textColor */,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      color: buttonColor,
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Text(text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: textColor,
            fontSize: 20.0,
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

You can define your button color like the one in the [answer given above/below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53533263/8164116)  too.

**[UPDATE]** 
*As per request from the comments, this is how you pass a function for `onPressed`*

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Button Theme"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green),
      body: Center(
        child: MyButton( //My custom button 
        text: "Hit me",
        onPressed: () { print("Ouch! Easy pal!! :p ") },
        textColor = const Color(SOME CUSTOM COLOUR)
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, please provide also an example on how to pass the onPressed function to MyButton?

Comment: @cwhisperer Done :)

Answer (score 6):

You can define theme on material widget like

Inside MaterialApp Widget

```
    theme: ThemeData(     
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  wordSpacing: 2,
                  letterSpacing: 2))),
```

Use

```
  ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => print('okay'),
          child: Text('Elevated Button'),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

For applying generic color to buttons and other similar widgets pass `ThemeData` with `primarySwatch` as below to the theme parameter of your MaterialApp at the root. Thus material app will use different shades of your primary color.

```
static const Color colorPrimary = Color(0xffFFFFFF);

ThemeData(
    primaryColor: colorPrimary,
    primarySwatch: MaterialColor(
      colorPrimary.value, 
      const <int, Color>{
        50: colorPrimary,
        100: colorPrimary,
        200: colorPrimary,
        300: colorPrimary,
        400: colorPrimary,
        500: colorPrimary,
        600: colorPrimary,
        700: colorPrimary,
        800: colorPrimary,
        900: colorPrimary,
      },
    ),
  );
```