# Override widget style in Flutter

Tags: flutter, themes

**Problem**: How can I automatically (if possible) style all [`RaisedButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html) widgets in my app a certain way?

---

I am converting an app from native Android to Flutter. In this application, all primary action buttons are rounded, gray, and have a white border. In Android, this was as simple as defining a style in `styles.xml` and setting `<Button style="MyPrimaryButton"/>`.

In Flutter, on the other hand, I can only find examples (including the one from the [theming docs](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/themes#using-a-theme)) that set individual properties using `property: Theme.of(context).property` and there doesn't seem to be a way to pass style properties other than colors and fonts.

Below is the style I would like to use for all `RaisedButton` widgets:

```
RaisedButton(
  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
  elevation: 0,
  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30)),
)
```

This [purportedly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50274444/2662227) was closed as primarily opinion-based but I am not asking for your opinion. I am asking if there *is* a way to style these buttons, preferably that does not involve copy-pasting the widget source code into my own class as the accepted answer recommends (though if that is still the only way to do it then that may very well be the answer).

Comment: why don't you set button theme at MaterialApp theme level ?

Comment: I think I was unclear on how exactly theming worked but I understand it better thanks to the answer Hemanth provided and see now how it is used.

Comment: for Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53533263/10269042

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that one when I skimmed for duplicates; my bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can actually achieve it by extending `RaisedButton` class and overriding the default properties that you need.

Example:

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: MyButton(onClicked: () => null,child: Text('Sample'),),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends RaisedButton {
  const MyButton({@required this.onClicked, this.child})
      : super(onPressed: onClicked, elevation: 0.0, child: child);

  final VoidCallback onClicked;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        buttonColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        buttonTheme: Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.copyWith(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: const BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 1.0,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
            ),
      ),
      child: Builder(builder: super.build),
    );
  }
}
```

Use `MyButton` where ever you wanted `RaisedButton` with your style.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh okay I was looking in the wrong place; giving it a try now. Looking over the code, is there a reason `elevation` is included in the call to `super` instead of in the `build` method with the other properties? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing down the properties to the super class. This is important and you can see I'm reusing the `build` method of super class.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract your already `customized widget` and then use it `everywhere`.

**Here you have 03 possibilities :**

Use it like **Local Variable** , **Widget** or **Method** .

1- **Local Variable**
**Code :**

```
var raisedButton = RaisedButton(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      elevation: 0,
      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30)),
      onPressed: null,
    );
```

**Usage:**

```
Container(child: raisedButton),
```

**2-Method**

**Code :**

```
RaisedButton buildRaisedButton(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          elevation: 0,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          onPressed: null,
        );
  }
```

**Use:**

```
Container(child: buildRaisedButton(context)),
```

**3- Widget**

**Code:**

```
 class MyRaisedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            elevation: 0,
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.white, width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            onPressed: null,
          );
  }
}
```

Use:

```
Container( child: MyRaisedButton()),
```

Note that you can do it quickly by clicking on your widget and do **(ctrl +)**.

The result will be:

[image]